# Tool that gets e-Mail and prints out attachments

Tags: windows, email, services

Okay, this is a VERY long shot, but it's worth a try: Is there a tool that runs as a Windows Service, regularly checks a POP3 e-Mail account and for every mail, prints out the attachments (PDF or XPS)?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a service I'm aware of however you could so something to an email client. Here are [two](http://www.techhit.com/outlook/automatically_print_email_messages.html) [solutions](http://email.about.com/od/mozillathunderbirdtips/qt/et_auto_print.htm) for Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can write one using the [samples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MimeClient.aspx) on Code Project, and manage the printing of documents using the API according to each MIME type.

Well, that's how I'd do it.

Comment: There's a simpler way to do it, using a system namespac in VB08. I'm a bit fuzzy now but it could be done.

Comment: Problem is that I'm a .net Developer, and there is no supported way to print from a .net Windows Service (neither System.Printing now System.Drawing.Printed are supported), so I would have to use P/Invoke around the native Win32 GDI API, and that's not as much fun as it may sound :(

Comment: Yup, not fun at all. Good luck with that.